# DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated

Tags: python-3.x, deprecation-warning

I'm trying to recover an old script of mine, which has always worked. Since I switched to Python 3 though, I'm having a lot of problems. This error came up after launching the script:

```
DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated
```

This is the line of the code which presents the problem:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@title='Consent all cookies']").click()
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Please include some code for context.  Which library is that from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Then replace this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@title='Consent all cookies']").click()
```

with this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@title='Consent all cookies']").click()
```

Comment: I made the change and It works now, thanks!